# How to post on a business page's 'visitor posts' through my app using Swift

Tags: swift, facebook, post

I'm writing an iOS app for a business using the latest version of `Swift` and `Xcode`. One of the requirements is to allow the user of the app to post through the app to the business's Facebook page, specifically to the `Visitor` Posts section.

I've already installed `Cocoapods` and set up my pod file to include the various Facebook entities, like Facebook login. But I'm at a loss for how to proceed further.

I couldn't find many examples of just posting to a `Facebook` page, but the ones I did find are confusing as they say they are for Swift development, but include a lot of objective C. Can anyone point me to documentation on how to post a line of text to the 'Visitors Posts' section of a page using Swift?

Comment: This might help to some extent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104943/posting-as-a-facebook-page-using-swift

Comment: Thanks for the link. This was helpful. I think I've got it working, now.

Comment: you can share your code in answer to help someone else in future.